# Unable to preview Laravel project on AWS Cloud9

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-artisan, aws-cloud9

I'm learning laravel and I've installed everything on an ec2 instance. The problem is when I run php artisan serve, the preview that pops up shows this image:

[error message from aws c9 preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK9rf.png)
(unable to load http preview)

I've tried running it as such:

`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080.`

But even when I open the preview in a new page using my public IP address, I get a "This site can't be reached, xx.xx.xx.xx took too long to respond."

I suspect the problem is that laravel is loading an HTTP site and according to AWS documentation, it only provides https support. noted here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-app-preview-http

Comment: I suggest you use backticks ( ` ) around word "ec2" and any code or output of code.

Comment: Have you been able to solved the issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: @SandroPalmieri I don’t remember :/ it was something stupid IIRC, but if you figure it out feel free to post the answer and I will mark it as such!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your public IP to open the webpage unless you open the public access in Security Group.  Check this website.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html